# Windows.Universal Javascript PWA app uses Edge legacy instead of Edge Chromium

Tags: progressive-web-apps, microsoft-edge, windows-10-universal

Wondering what causes my PWA app to use edge 18 engine as runtime when the Edge Chromium is present on my windows machine.

Because of this I have to downgrade my Javascript target to es2016 (es6) as I compile my typescript.

I am using Aplication.Manifest and generating a package msix.

Could my Applicication.Manifest playing any part ? Or is there any way it can be changed so that the runtime uses the current version of Edge Chromium engine if at all it is possible.

Wondering you build your javascript based native apps and target a better runtime in 2022 ?

```
  <Dependencies>
    <TargetDeviceFamily Name="Windows.Universal" MinVersion="10.0.17134.0" MaxVersionTested="10.0.18363.1139"/>
  </Dependencies>
```

Update:
To clarify I am using appx package manifest and creating an app with a link to a PWA site.

Comment: I'd like to know that are you using WebView?

Comment: yes - but not explicitly as I use makeAppx and provide index.html and index.js so thinking it must runs in some kind of webview

Comment: Well, AFAIK WebView only supports Edge Legacy while [WebView2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/) is for the new Edge (not even a UWP app). I suggest you can try WebView2 and add it to your code.

Comment: @KendrickLi what do i need to do in my manifest to make it webview2? Since I don't have any html/js that spells out webview there must be something that turns webview2 from manifest.xml

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at [this sample code](https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/WebView2Samples/blob/main/SampleApps/webview2_sample_uwp/Package.appxmanifest) from Microsoft official UWP sample using WebView2. See if this can help you. I would suggest following the official [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/get-started/winui2) to make sure everything works fine.